# Is there any path function in PHP for matching path mask?

Tags: php, path

I'm looking for a native solution for path mask matching like in console.

Let's say we have the path `/path/to/some_filename.txt`
Mask

```
/path/*/some?file*.txt
```

will be matched.

```
var_dump(test_path('/path/to/some_filename.txt', '/path/*/some?file*.txt'));
//true
```

It should work with a string only, but not using real files.

Yes, it can be converted into a regular expression, I have [my own code](https://github.com/andkirby/commithook/blob/1c0e071e3abb023cae491c74adfdc4ffc3ea4539/src/lib/PreCommit/Helper/PathMatch.php), but I would like to use completely the same like in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)

```
var_dump(fnmatch('/path/*/some?file*.txt', '/path/to/some_filename.txt'));
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, it works! Oh this obvious function names! :) Thanks.

Comment: Another in the great tradition of PHP function naming: I believe that it is abbreviated FileNameMATCH(), though it works perfectly happily with any string, not simply filenames